# "Come over" and etymology of other idioms

Tags: etymology, idioms

Can someone explain the etymology of using *over* in expressions like *come over to* and *go over to* as in "pay a casual visit"?

Is there a source for the etymology of idiomatic expressions somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is one example (well, pair of examples) where an analytical approach is better than an overall view - looking at the semantics of the preposition **over**, rather than treating 'come over to' as a lexeme best considered opaque.  (I'll have to bite the bullet and treat *over* as an intransitive preposition in these examples.)

Kota Kodachi, in 'A Study of Prototype Formation of the Meanings of Prepositions...' at http://www.paaljapan.org/resources/proceedings/PAAL10/pdfs/kodachi.pdf , looks at the semantics involved in the various senses of various English prepositions, suggesting a logical hierarchy that the senses fit into. Though he majors on the prepositions **at**, **in** and **on**, I'll suggest an analogous treatment of **over**.

One model illustrated, put forward by Tanaka, is that prepositions have:

1. a central (prototypical) sense which is spatial (locative or directional);
2. a less central looser spatial sense;
3. non-spatial (in the geometric sense) senses.

(Other models differ; temporal usage may be seen as an alternative prototypical usage.)

Illustrating Tanaka's model with **on**:

1. on the table / floor
2. on the bus / train
3. on time / on the hour / on fire / on tenterhooks / on good terms with / on the pull ...

It could be argued that a three-point scale is not adequately differentiated - does 'on television' come in category 2, 3, or somewhere between?

On this model, **over** in *come over to* is the less central looser spatial sense:

1a. over the lake (= above the lake)

1b. over the lake (= from one side to the other)

1c. over the river (= on the other bank)

2 not 1. go over [the intervening ground] to see someone

3 not 2. Brazil's victory over Spain

The best overall treatment of fixed expressions (including idioms) that I know of is

**Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English: A Corpus-Based Approach** by

Rosamund Moon