# What does "over" mean in this question?

Tags: adverbs

I'd like to know whether "over" is necessary or not in the following question:

> *Do you want to come **over** for dinner tonight?*

Comment: [Come over](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/come-over) is a phrasal verb. Their meanings can't be _figured out_ by processing the verb and the preposition separately.

Comment: It will be the height of hypocrisy for me to say this to you, @TusharRaj, but that comment would make a fine answer (which will allow us to dispense with this question).

Comment: Haha, hypocrisy indeed! I posted it as a comment because the question shows no research. It's too basic, and deserves to be closed or asked at ELL, and that's how I think it should be 'dispensed with'. The comment was merely intended to help the new user. In fact, my inclination to only answer quality questions exists a great deal because of you.

Comment: @TusharRaj Well, how can I argue with that? VtC now...

Comment: This is a duplicate of ' “Come over” and etymology of other idioms'; I've been rather busy close-voting of late.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd rather VtC with a pointer to OP at ELL, where his future questions will get better answers, rather the close as a dupe of a question about etymology (which I imagine OP has no interest in).

Comment: @Tushar Raj It's debatable how unitary 'come over' is here. An intermediate usage of 'over' is best inferred, somewhere between the pure prepositional (come over the bridge next time) and the highly metaphorical (go over the details).

Comment: @Dan Bron I interpreted the question as meaning 'Can someone explain the role of _over_ in "Come over and see us next week"; OP there accepted the answer. Have you read it?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't disagree. If the post indicated that the OP is familiar with the concept of phrasal verbs, and was trying to establish how literal `over` is here, and in what sense; this would have been a different question. However, currently it is a poor one by ELU standards. Hence the closevote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right that I haven't read it yet; my primary motivation is to let OP, who is an ELL, know about the stack ELL.

Comment: @Tushar Raj _Which_ concept of 'phrasal verbs'? I've had a discussion with someone who thinks that 'change of meaning between matrix verb and multi-word verb' is the **controlling factor** in classification, whereas the [British Council grammar website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/phrasal-verbs) only goes as far as 'Often this gives the verb a new meaning'.  Terminology isn't standardised.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: _Any_ of them.

Comment: @Tushar Raj 'Come over and see us' is far more transparent than 'Take over the cooking and make sure you don't leave the kitchen'. Few grammars I've seen examine variability in verb-prepositiony thing cohesiveness.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Come over" and etymology of other idioms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108152/come-over-and-etymology-of-other-idioms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English has many verbs that change their meaning when a preposition is added.

In your question, one could say either

> Do you want to come over for dinner tonight?

or

> Do you want to come for dinner tonight?

The first feels a little more colloquial to a native English speaker, the second a little more stilted. I suspect that the colloquial feel has to do with the use of the phrasal verb, *come over*.

Consider these alternate sentences:

> Jane ran up the hill.
>
> Jane ran up the tab.

In the first, the verb is "ran," and it is followed by a prepositional phrase, "up the hill."

In the second, there is a *phrasal verb*, "ran up," and it is followed by a direct object.

There is a good treatment of phrasal verbs at https://english.stackexchange.com/a/131679/3306 .

Comment: When do you come 'over' for dinner; and when do you come 'round' for dinner?

Comment: If you were outside playing, I suppose your mom would ask you to "come in for dinner." If you were unconscious, the nurse's aide could ask you to "come to for dinner." If you were a cheap brother-in-law, your wife might ask you to "come through for dinner."

Comment: And if you were a next door neighbour I might ask you to "come round" for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

According to [macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-over), *over* has a specific function here.

Please check sense #3 on the link above.

Which is:

Sense 3 [INTRANSITIVE] to visit someone in the place where they are, especially their house

Example: Why don’t you come over for dinner?

Comment: Please quote sense #3 from the link above, *[in your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/273503)*.